# SQL Server Instance login issue

Tags: sql-server, login

I've just brought up a new installation of SQL Server 2008.  I installed the default instance as well as one named instance.

I'm having a problem connecting to the named instance from anywhere besides the server itself with any user besides 'sa'.

I am running in mixed mode.  I have a login/user that has a known username.  Using that user/login, I can properly connect when directly on the server.

When I attempt to login from anywhere else, I recieve a "Login failed for user ''", with Error 18456.  In the log file in the server, I see a reason that doesn't seem to help: "Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided.".  However, that user/login DOES exist, as I can use it locally.

There are no further details about the error.  Where can I start to find something to help me with this?  I've tried deleting and recreating the user, as well as just creating a new one from scratch--same result, locally fine, remotely an error.

**EDIT:** Partially Resolved.

I'm now passed the base issue--the clients were trying to connect via the default instance.  I don't know why.  So, once proper ports were opened in the firewall, and a static port assigned to the named instance, I can now connect--BUT ONLY if I specify the connection as  *Server,Port*.  SQLBrowser is apparently not helping/working in this case.  I've verified it IS running, and done a stop/restart after my config changes, but no difference yet.

Comment: In phrase "When I attempt to login from anywhere else", what is I? Webapp, SSMS?

Comment: Both :)  SSMS from a remote machine, or any application on a remote machine.

Comment: If you create another SQL login on the named instance, does that work?

Comment: Nope, same issue.

Comment: Now... you can specify the server\port you can connect that way, but not with server\name is that correct?

Comment: That's correct, I can connect with  ServerName,PortNumber, but not with ServerName\InstanceName.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that the connections work when you do Server,Port I think your issue is related to not having the SQL Browser port opened on the firewall (1434). Honestly, though, I think you're safer if you hard-code the ports.

Comment: @reallyJim: Make sure that port 1434 us an UDP port and not a TCP. Also try to use **portqryui** tool from Microsoft that makes it very easy to query SQL Browser and check its response.